# Что из этого является говнокодом?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, смотрю курс по Java, и что то меня наталкивает на то, что автор курса показывает говнокод. Так ли это?

Как я вижу реализацию простейшего калькулятора:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shitcode {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 1 число: ");
    float a = scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Введите Ваше 2 число: ");
    float b = scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Результатом сложения введеных Вами чисел является " + (a + b));

}

}
```

И как его преподносит автор:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shitcode {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    float first, second, result;
    System.out.print("Enter first num: ");
    first = num.nextFloat();
    System.out.print("Enter second num: ");
    second = num.nextFloat();
    result = first + second;
    System.out.println("Result is - " + result);

}

}
```

Comment: Каждый **очет, как он хочет... Вполне себе нормально заранее объявить переменные и использовать затем в коде. В целом пока криминального ничего нет..... надо смотреть гораздо бОльшего объёма куски кода имхо. Рассматривать две строчки - ну серьёзно..... может ещё точки и запятые смотреть?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что для код-ревью есть конкретная метка с определёнными правилами, всё остальное "просмотрите код" не относится ни к одной тематике и целей ресурса

Comment: а что есть "говнокод"? по сабжу: все одинаково. твоя реализация для "здесь и сейчас". у автора - "для возможных будущих действий с переменными". ни то ни то не говнокод. говнокод будет дальше))

Comment: Автор возможно раньше на Delphi/Pascal кодил, вот привычка и осталась :)

Comment: Понял ребят, спасибо